# Drawer visibility

Tags: c#, visibility, drawer

How do I open/show a left navigation drawer when I navigate to the page?  I'm looking for something like the following:

```
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
{
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DrawerLayout);
    var drawer = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
    drawer.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to tell us what exactly do you want to achieve using an example.

Comment: The code above doesn't work.

Comment: What does `ViewStates` accomplish here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling visibility wont show the drawer, you have to call OpenDrawer() like so:

```
drawerLayout.OpenDrawer(Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.Start);
```

when the drawerLayout is:

```
drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
```

in your code you refer to *NavigationView* as the *drawer*.

Take a look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-left-drawer-layout) tutorial.

Comment: I thought the NavigationView was the left side menu, guess I was wrong, thanks!